# Exact string match

Tags: regex, r

A very trivial question - tried a few iterations and still couldnt get the right answer. Maybe "grep" is not the right command or my understanding is completely off.

I have a string:

```
"Part 2.2 are Secondary objectives of this study".
```

I am trying to do an exact match on: "Secondary objective". I thought I could use   "fixed=TRUE" here, but it matches both.

```
> str5 = "Part 2.2 are Secondary objectives of this study"
> line<-grep("Secondary objectives",str5,fixed=TRUE)
> line
[1] 1

> str5 = "Part 2.2 are Secondary objectives of this study" 
> line<-grep("Secondary objective",str5,fixed=TRUE)
> line
[1] 1
```

I understand that "grep" is doing exactly as  it should. It is searching for the string "Secondary objective" which is technically in the original string. But my understanding is I could do an exact match using the "fixed=TRUE' command. But obviously I am mistaken.

If "grep" with "fixed=TRUE" is not the right command for exact match,what will work? "str_match" did not work either.
If my pattern is: "Secondary objective", it should return "integer(0)" 
but if my pattern is "Secondary objectives", it should return 1.

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks much! - simak

---

Update: Trying out Arun's suggestion below - works fine as is.

```
 str5 = "Part 2.2 are Secondary objectives of this study"
> grep("(Secondary objectives)(?![[:alpha:]])",str5, perl=TRUE)
[1] 1

> grep("(Secondary objective)(?![[:alpha:]])",str5, perl=TRUE)
integer(0)
```

> str5 = "Part 2.2 are Secondary objectives of this study"
>   grep("(pat)(?![[:alpha:]])",str5, perl=TRUE)
>      integer(0)

```
However when I did this:

> str5 = "Part 2.2 are Secondary objectives of this study"
> pat <- "Secondary objectives"
> grep("(pat)(?![[:alpha:]])",str5, perl=TRUE)
integer(0)

Thought I can call "pat" inside "grep". Is that incorrect? Thanks!
```

Comment: And I told you to do: `pat <- paste0("(", "Secondary objectives", ")", "(?![[:alpha:]])")` and try `grep(pat, str5, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Yep tried that. Didnt work either.....

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? It gives me `integer(0)` for `Secondary objective` and `1` for `Secondary objectives`. It seems fine to me!

Answer (score 1):

One way I could think of is to use `negative lookahead` (with `perl=TRUE` option). That is, we check if there is no other alphabet immediately after your pattern and if so return `1` else no match.

```
grep("(Secondary objective)(?![[:alpha:]])", x, perl=TRUE)
# integer(0)

grep("(Secondary objectives)(?![[:alpha:]])", x, perl=TRUE)
# [1] 1
```

This'd work even if the pattern you were searching is at the end because we search for anything that's not an alphabet. That is,

```
grep("(this stud)(?![[:alpha:]])", x, perl=TRUE)
# integer(0)

grep("(this study)(?![[:alpha:]])", x, perl=TRUE)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks Arun for your response. It worked fine when passing the string directly in the grep statement. But if I passed the pattern through a variable, grep returned 0. str5 = "Part 2.2 are Secondary objectives of this study"
pat <- "Secondary objectives"
grep("(pat)(?![[:alpha:]])",str5, perl=TRUE)
Is the syntax not right? Thanks: Simak

Comment: Not sure, but try making your pattern like this: `str <- "Secondary objective"; pat <- paste0("(", str, ")", "(?![[:alpha:]])")`.

Comment: @Arun is there some way to use the word boundary matching? `\b` I'm not sure because I'm not very good at regex

Comment: Could you please edit your post explaining what dint work and what you're trying to do? Because the way I see it, this answers your question per se.